# Reboot an EC2 instance when cloudwatch logs trigger Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I added  Cloudwatch Logs trigger to Lambda function, which gets triggered when a particular word is found(for example: 'application started') and then it processes certain functions like sending an SNS Notification. What I need is help with the python code to reboot an EC2 instance from inside the lambda function. I've seen everyone doing start and stop EC2 instances from lambda's but not rebooting them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.reboot_instances), which explains the `reboot_instances` command from `boto3` package.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2.reboot_instances(InstanceIds=['string'])
```

So simple.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked. Sorry for asking a dumb question. I am new to lambdas. and one more follow up question. is there any way you could check if the ec2 instance has been rebooted?

Comment: You could check using this, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status

Comment: Awesome. Thank you